# jstree - How to load ancestry data?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jstree, ancestry

In rails 4.2.2, I am trying to load an ancestry data for jstree but it is not loading & it is not showing any error also. Referred from http://tech.sunilnkumar.com/2014/03/28/tree-hierarchy-with-js-tree-and-ancestry/

When I tried the below script in javascript console,

```
  $("#category-hierarchy").jstree({
    "json_data": {
      "ajax" : {
        "url" : $("#category-hierarchy").attr('data-path'),
        "data" : function (n) {
         return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
       }
     }
   },
   plugins : ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
   themes : {"theme": "default", "icons":false, "dots": true, "open":true},
   core: {"animation": 100}
 });
```

I got an result like,

```
$.jstree.core {_id: 1, _cnt: 0, _wrk: null, _data: Object, _model: Object…}
_cnt: 0
_data: Object
_id: 1
_model: Object
_wrk: null
element: jQuery.fn.init[1]
settings: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Ancestry data for `Category.arrange_serializable` is

```
[{"id"=>1, "ancestry"=>nil, "user_id"=>1, "asset_id"=>nil, "root_node"=>true, "created_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "children"=>[{"id"=>2, "ancestry"=>"1", "user_id"=>1, "asset_id"=>1, "root_node"=>false, "created_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "children"=>[]}, {"id"=>3, "ancestry"=>"1", "user_id"=>1, "asset_id"=>2, "root_node"=>false, "created_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 14 Sep 2015 04:53:25 UTC +00:00, "children"=>[]}]}]
```

How to generate jstree for an ancestry data?

Comment: A side note - you should probably consider upgrading to jstree v.3, as v.1 is quite old and no longer supported.